# Get all Content thats between Square Brackets: Regex

Tags: regex, regex-group, regex-greedy

I have the follwing string:

**"[parameters('ECC_Shipment_Trigger_properties_pl_ecc_shipment_adls_sql_parameters_File_system')]"**

and I would like to write a regular expression that return only:

**parameters('ECC_Shipment_Trigger_properties_pl_ecc_shipment_adls_sql_parameters_File_system')**

Keeping in mind that I only need content that starts as:

**parameters('some string')**

So far I have come up with **(?<=[parameters(').+?(?='))** which only returns the text between single quotes.

for testing, I am using https://regexr.com/

How can I modify my current regex to get this result?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The positive lookbehind is an assertion (non consuming), so this part `(?<=\[parameters\(')` means that from the current position it asserts what is on the left is `[parameters(`.

Instead of a lookaround, you could use a capturing group and a [negated character class](https://www.regular-expressions.info/charclass.html#negated) matching any char except a `'` instead.

The value is in the first capturing group.

```
\[(parameters\('[^']+'\))\]
```

[Regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/9im3Jw/1)

If you want to use lookaround, this might be an option, asserting what is on the left is `[` and what is on the right is `]`

```
(?<=\[)parameters\('[^']+'\)(?=\])
```

[Regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/Jg1Eke/1)